# Java checkstyle import statement indentation

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm trying to prevent inconsistent indentations in import statements like this:

```java
...
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Before;            // ← this line
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
...
```

The [Indentation module](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_misc.html#Indentation)
doesn't do the trick, nor does the [import config](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_imports.html)

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m pretty sure the Indentation rule is only meant for content of blocks (if, for, while, switch, etc.).

Use [RegexpSinglelineJava](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_regexp.html#RegexpSinglelineJava) instead:

```
<module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
    <property name="format" value="^\s+import\b"/>
    <property name="message" value="import statements must start in the first column."/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks. It's surprising that import statements are not covered out of the box, to me at least.

Comment: So. It turns out that the [Indentation module](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_misc.html#Indentation) does **not** cover `import` statements in 6.19. However it *does* cover `import` statements in 8.37.

So to summarize: use @VGR's solution above for 6.19 (6.x too?) and the Indentation module for 8.37 (8.x too ?). Cheers @VGR!